# javah method header not generate?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I use command,

```
javah -jni example.lib.Utils
```

output example_lib_Utils.h

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class example_lib_Utils */

#ifndef _Included_example_lib_Utils
#define _Included_example_lib_Utils
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

my java code,

```
public class Utils {
    public static boolean _exp( InputStream is, File oF) throws Exeption {
      .....
     return false
    }
}
```

how can i generate method header?

Comment: You can generate method header of native methods only. mark your method as `public static native boolean _exp( InputStream is, File oF) throws Exeption;`

Comment: thanks,  it's working.